# 120VAC Cable Connector Type

Tags: ac, connector

I have a 120VAC, 0.01 amp motorized ball valve that I need to plug into a control box. A pcb inside the box turns the valve on and off. The valve is shipped with an attached 2-wire cable that ends in bare leads. The system is designed to handle multiple 120VAC components inside the box, so I can't switch to a lower voltage DC valve.

I'm looking for a safe, panel-mount connector to attach to the valve's bare leads.

I've previously used barrel power connectors I had available, but these are only rated to around 30V. I've looked at IEC 320-C7 type plugs, which have a great panel mount female connector, but I can only find IEC 320-C7 cables that are pre-assembled. I'd prefer to solder the valve's leads onto a plug end, like with a barrel or audio connector, instead of attaching it to another set of leads.

I think it would be dangerous to run 120vac through the barrel power connectors (only rated to 30V), correct?

Is there a better type of connector to do this? Or do I need to solder or crimp the valve's bare leads to an IEC 320-C7 plug?

Edit: After researching IEC 320-C7 cables more, I think they're only available with factory terminated cable. [Here's](https://www.takefiveaudio.com/contents/49-c7pc) a link to a DIY site for making your own, but I need something that isn't hacked. I think I'll use Anderson Power Pole Connectors (as recommended below) or JST SM connectors.

Comment: There are plenty of stand alone plugs to find in your local hardware store

Comment: This is for a product that will be for sale, so I need something that will look more professional. I'd also prefer something that's not a wall plug.

Comment: Why not gland it in then hardwire internally?

Comment: You might consider Jones plugs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The valve needs to be able to be unplugged, so it can't be hardwired.

Comment: What are the two wires going to the valve? 120VAC switched-hot and neutral?

Comment: @Harper yes, 120VAC switched-hot and neutral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Anderson Power Pole connectors. They are commonly used in radio applications. They look professional, have a variety of configuration options (including a variety of panel mount options), so they're easy to work with when you don't already have a solution in mind. The "finger proof" style are recommended for high voltage AC use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Those sort of look like JST connectors, which I'm already using inside the box. I just looked for panel mount JST, which I didn't realize exists, and found JST SM connectors, which seem promising, too.

Comment: For 120Vac, you might want to use this variant for the neutral connection: https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/7e52554afa0b4177c46e58f66663b22f.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with mains voltage, use mains voltage rated equipment.

NEMA dominates North American mains connectors, and they have [connectors](http://www.everything-about-rving.com/images/NEMAPlugChart.jpg) for a wide variety of voltages and currents.  I'm **scouring the Internet** looking for one with 120V and neutral pins.  **Scouring!**  Might take me awhile...

... A-ha.  Found one.

[image]  src:ebay

*betcha thought I was going to post something else.*

This honey is a NEMA L1-15R. **L** means locking. **1** means [NEMA 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_1): 120+neutral (no safety earthing). **15** means 15A max (the smallest size). **R** means *receptacle*, P means plug.   It's an oddball connector that appears beefy and industrial.  It lacks *earthing* but earthing is unnecessary if the pump and supply are part of the same metal chassis. *Truth be told, it's simply the "L" version of NEMA 1-15:*

[image]  src:SE

*Except the neutral blade is supposed to be wider, 8mm.*

Now, I know you don't want to use a straight NEMA 1-15, but there would be a good reason to do so:  **Testing**.  You could field-test the valve by plugging it into any extension cord and see if it runs.  You could tell if the machine is energizing the socket by using:

[image]
src: [etsy](https://www.etsy.com/listing/241723674/night-light-harry-potter-gryffindor)

*Sophisticated NEMA 1-15 test equipment.*

Conversely, though, this might invite abuse, a clever customer might use jury-rigged tricks to bypass the intent of the machine.

If you want *even more* obscure, consider NEMA 18, L18 or L21.  These connectors have a neutral and *three* 120V hot terminals -- the expectation is that the three 120V legs are in 3-phase "wye" configuration giving 208V, but that is not required.  You could use this connector to control 1, 2 or 3 valves.  Nothing will explode if these were cross-plugged with actual 208.

[image]
[image]
[image]

*NEMA 18-20R, NEMA L18-20R, and earthed NEMA L21-20R. It kinda looks to me like an L21-20R might accept an L18-20 plug.*

You could do the same trick with NEMA 10 or 14, which have *two* 120V hot terminals. However NEMA L14 is probably the most common twist-lock connector out there.  If you have more than 3 valves to control, and want to key the connectors so they can't be cross-plugged, use a variety.

All of these NEMA connectors are specifically made for what you are doing.